# Derive additional columns based on existing column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

I have 500 records with 10 columns. Based on the Date column I want to create two additional columns `(date_id, record_id)`. The date column is unique.

- Date_id column value should be: `F + date + unique identifier`.
- Record_id column value should be: `C + date + unique identifier`.

For example:

```
Date     
15Jul2017
```

Expected output:

```
Date             date_id                     record_id 
---------------  --------------------------  --------------
15Jul2017        F+15Jul2017+1               C+15Jul2017+1
15Jul2017        F+15Jul2017+2               C+15Jul2017+2
...so on until 500 records
15Jul2017        F+15Jul2017+500             C+15Jul2017+500
```

Comment: How are you storing the date?  Why not as a date?

Comment: This is a violation of 1NF, you probably want to add just a column for the id.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  i have a value that is stored as 2017-07-15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.date,
       ('F+' || date || '+' || row_number() over (order by date)) as date_id,
       ('c+' || date || '+' || row_number() over (order by date)) as record_id
from t;
```

If your date is really stored as a date and not a string, then you may need to format it to your preferred format.

Comment: Ah... I always forget the `row_number()` function.